# How do you make a copy of wine to a dvd?

Tags: 12.04, wine, laptop, dvd

I am trying to make a copy of wine to a dvd so that I can put it on my laptop. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Define Make a Copy?  The application itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to backup your configuration, just copy the .wine folder in your home directory.

It is maybe usefull to use a compression program:
`zip -r9 myWineBackup.zip ~/.wine/`

To burn the zip file to DVD just use brasero which should be installed by default:

Start a data project by clicking on the menu entry
[image]

And then add files:
[image]

Comment: Manuel, thank you so much! It is compressing right now. After the compression, will it automatically be in my home folder, or should I still try to copy it? I don't know how to copy from the command line. Is it cp ./wine/home/brian?

Comment: Mitch, sorry I didn't see your post. Yes, I want to burn a copy of the application so that I can install it into my laptop. I want to install MIDI Uno on the laptop.

Comment: You can go into the home directory with the filemanager and copy the compressed (myWineBackup.zip in my example) as youl like.

Comment: Manuel, ok I got the Wine and MIDI files in my home directory. How do you send it to a DVD? I try to click on "send to" and it says it does but when I put it in the laptop it is still blank.

Comment: go to the dash and type 'brasero' it is the default program to burn stuff to a disk. You want to make a data disk.

Comment: Manual, ok I am very close. I successfully compressed wine. However, I am getting an error message when I try to copy it from the command line. The first time I tried to copy it to the folder it was completely empty, just a file. Here is the message-cp myWineBackup.zip/home/brian/Documents/
cp: missing destination file operand after ‘myWineBackup.zip/home/brian/Documents/’

Comment: Success! I managed to move it to my laptop. Thank you all.

Comment: Ok, seems that you missed a space ;)